# XMLHttpRequest goes over last three readyStates immediately

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write a code that tests `XMLHttpRequest` to check the different kind of readyState values. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest) there are five possible, consecutive states. I've built a little PHP code that forces a pause between each state:

```
<?php

// Build the json
$msg = json_encode(array(
    'status' => 0,
    'msg' => 'Lorem ipsum dillum sit amet')
);

// Divide the message in two parts
$msgLen = strlen($msg);
$h1 = $msgLen / 2;
$h2 = $msgLen - $h1;

// Wait, then send the headers
sleep(1);
header('Content-type: application/json');
flush();

// Wait, the send the first part
sleep(1);
echo substr($msg, 0, $h1);
flush();

// Wait, the send the second part
sleep(1);
echo substr($msg, $h2);
```

The problem is that it does not seem to work. The request instantly goes from 1 - OPENED through 4 - DONE, instead of doing a pause between each state.

Also, two curious things happen:

- In Firefox and IE, the readyState 1 - OPENED gets fired twice.
- In IE10, there's indeed a pause when the headers are sent, but no pause between the two parts of the content.

Comment: What is your PHP server configuration (PHP version, linux/windows)? Take a look on [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) to see that `sleep` might not work in your stack.

Comment: `flush` might not work on your server. Output buffering and gzip encoding for example can conspire to defeat your attempts.

Comment: @wiktor sleep is actually working, I can "feel" the delay. If I delete the `sleep` commands the response is immediate.

@Neil I'll take a look. I was trying it on a wampserver stack with the default configuration anyways.